# Cross-Platform Styling using the Intel XDK

Tags: android, ios, mobile, frameworks, intel-xdk

I recently downloaded the Intel XDK and I've noticed that when an app is run on different devices, the style is reflected by the OS the app is being run on. (For example, when run on android, almost everything is black, as opposed to iOS 7, where everything is white) Everything is functioning the same, just not looking the same. I realize that the XDK is using native styles, but is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the auto style selector feature of App Framework. You're either running a demo app based on App Framework or have built your own app using App Framework. This is an optional (defaults to "on") feature of App Framework that will swap in a CSS file that is tuned to the platform.

See the [App Framework documentation page](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php) for more info. In particular, the "[OS Themes](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_themes)" page.